# Order by pivot column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models, `students` and `languages`. Each student can speak *n* languages with a certain *skill* via pivot table `student_language`. For example Mike speaks English with a skill of 3 and german with a skill of 7.

Here is the **student** model:

```
class Student extends \Eloquent {
    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Language')->withPivot('skill');
    }
}
```

And here is the **language** model:

```
class Language extends \Eloquent {
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Student')->withPivot('quality');
    }    
}
```

How can I get a list of students that speaks a language, and **sort them by their skill level**? In Fluent it would be something like this, but **I cannot use joins** and need to write it in Eloquent:

```
$students = DB::table('students')
    ->join('student_language', 'students.id', '=', 'student_language.student_id')
    ->where('student_language.language_id', '=', '1')
    ->orderBy("student_user.skill", "desc")
    ->get();
```

Thank you for any inputs.

*Edit: update*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't check this but you can try this

```
Student::with(['languages' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('pivot_skill', 'ASC');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does indeed work, but is terribly slow. I even got an `allowed memory size exhausted` exception. Is there a faster solution?

Comment: Arifs answer is correct because you said you cannot use joins. The code above will contain a nested select which is very slow in mysql (much faster in Postgresql). The fastest way is to use joins but you said you can't do that? (Why can't you use joins?)